# Typedef struct use in c

Tags: c, struct, typedef

```
struct pointsto_val_def
{
    unsigned int lhs;
    bitmap rhs;
    struct pointsto_val_def *next;
};
typedef struct pointsto_val_def *pointsto_val;

typedef pointsto_val *pointsto_val_hash;
```

Can the last two statements be simply replaced by this one statement?

```
typedef struct pointsto_val_def *pointsto_val_hash
```

Thanks in advance. Cheers.

Comment: Easier to try it and see what the compiler tells you, than it is to post a question and wait for an answer, isn't it?

Comment: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter8/typedef.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is no.Because the type of pointsto_val_hash is `struct pointsto_val_def**`, that means pointsto_val_hash is a pointer which is pointed to `struct pointsto_val_def*`.And your replacement means a pointer which is pointed to `struct pointsto_val_def`, they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace it with one `typedef` if you don't need the `_val` type, but with a double-pointer:

```
typedef struct pointsto_val_def** pointsto_val_hash;
```